# Numbers in initialization vector (IV) are all zeros

Tags: openssl, initialization-vector

I'm having trouble understanding the following sentence : "the numbers in initialization vector (IV) are all zeros (not the ASCII character '0').

My goal is to use openssl enc command to encrypt a file using aes-128-cbc with a key K (let's say 1234567890) and the iv that fulfil such requirements.

So far, I've tried not putting -iv option but it then says "iv undefined" because if option -K is used, option -iv must be provided. I've tried to used *-iv 0* but I'me not sure it is the correct one.

For the instance, I used:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -e -in input.txt -out output.txt -K 1234567890 -iv 0
```

Can please you help me illustrate the correct iv that fulfill the above requirements?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSL implementation of AES-CBC requires the IV to be of the same size as the block size - i.e. 128 bit in your case. `enc` manual page says:

```
-iv IV
    the actual IV to use: this must be represented as a string comprised only of hex digits.
```

It does not say, how all 128 bits are obtained if the IV, given on the command line, is shorter - as in your example command.

Fortunately source code of OpenSSL is available. We can see in `enc.c` that the IV is initialized to all zeros, and then the starting bytes are filled from the command-line argument:

```
[hiv is the value of the command-line option -iv:]

if ((hiv != NULL) && !set_hex(hiv, iv, sizeof iv)) {
    BIO_printf(bio_err, "invalid hex iv value\n");

[...]

int set_hex(char *in, unsigned char *out, int size)
{
    int i, n;
    unsigned char j;

    n = strlen(in);
    if (n > (size * 2)) {
        BIO_printf(bio_err, "hex string is too long\n");
        return (0);
    }
    memset(out, 0, size);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    .......
```

So, what you are doing - providing just a single zero for '-iv' - happens to produce the all-zeroes IV which you need.

Note that using a constant - and especially "typical", such as all zeros - IV is a bad security practice; [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) explains why.

Comment: IV length is not the size of the key - it's the size of the block. For AES-128 you're accidentally right though, because key size is equal to block size.

Answer (score 2):

For modes CBC, CFB or OFB you need initialization vector, which in length is equal to block size of a specific cipher. For AES you have 128 bits.

You can check your command by using -p, for example:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -e -in test.txt -out output.txt -K 1234567812346578 -iv 0 -p
```

Would give you :

```
salt=A086E8DE00000000
key=12345678123456781234567812345678
iv =00000000000000000000000000000000
```

If your key or IV is too short, it will pad it with zeroes till reaching the correct size.